# How to Render a JS response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following in my controller:

```
  return render :js => "alert('Hello Rails');"
```

Problem is it shows up as text and isn't running as JavaScript. Ideas why?

Comment: How are you looking at this?  In the browser?  All stylesheets show up as text when viewed in the browser.  What `render :js` is for is producing things that can be used as, for example, the target of `<script src="..."></script>` tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to remove the "return". The correct code would read

```
render :js => "alert('Hello Rails');"
```

Comment: ... and if that were the last line of the method, that too would render the supplied string with a MIME type of `text/javascript` and then would return.